# Determine point of interesction of plane with axis given points of plane

Tags: linear-algebra

> Q: The points $(2,-1,-2)$, $(1,3,12)$ and $(4,2,3)$ lie on a unique plane. Where does the plane cross the z-axis.

I understand that the point of intersection would occur at $(0,0,z)$ and I have to determine $z$. I'm not sure how to go about this question and my textbook does not provide an example of similar type. Any tips to get me started on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find the equation of a plane through three given points?  If so, do it, then substitute $x=0$, $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

there are two parallel vectors of the plane, namely
$$u=(1,3,12)-(2,-1,-2)=(-1,4,14)\\ v=(4,2,3)-(2,-1,-2)=(2,3,5)$$
So the perpendicular vector to the plane is
$$w=u\times v=(-22,33,-11)$$ Then the equation of the plane is
$$-22(x-1)+33(y-3)-11(z-12)=0\\ -2(x-1)+3(y-3)-(z-12)=0 \\$$ The plane cuts the z axis at
$$-2(0-1)+3(0-3)-(z-12)=0\implies z=2-9+12=5$$

## An alternative solution:

Let the equation be $$r=r_0+tu+sv\\=(2,-1,-2)+t(-1,4,14)+s(2,3,5)$$ Now let $r=(0,0,c)$ and solve for $c$. so we get
$$0=2-t+2s\\0=-1+4t+3s$$ we get that $s=-7/11,t=8/11$ and so
$$c=-2+14t+5s=5$$

Comment: I'm afraid this will not be an acceptable solution because we have not learned cross product in the class. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let that three point be A,B,C
Find the vector of AB and BC,
Then find the cross product of AB and BC.
Use the cross product and any point of A,B or C to form a equation of plane consisting these three points.Then substitute $x=0$ and $y=0$ into the equation of plane then i think you will get the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid this will not be an acceptable solution because we have not learned cross product in the class. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Let the equation of plane be $ax+by+cz=d$ and substitute the three given points into the equation to form a system of linear equation. Then find the value of a,b,c and d.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this approach. How would I go about solving for the system when d is unkown?

Comment: I think a,b,c will get the value in terms of d. Then after simplification the d will disappear. You may try.